# How to call a method on string change in C#?

Tags: c#, string, methods

need a bit of help here.

I need to know whether it's possible for a method to be called each time a string is changed.

Let's say I have a line

```
input = Console.ReadLine();
```

so that the user can change the value of the input string. How do I do it so that every time the input string changes, a method is called?

Comment: Check out [events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/8627sbea(v=vs.71).aspx)

Comment: This cannot be achieved out of the box, you would need a custom class that implements specific behavior. Note in passing that strings in C# never change -- they're immutable. New strings are created, but existing ones cannot change.

Comment: Why not simply call the method on the line after `input = Console.ReadLine();` ? If `input` is something other than a local variable, then it would probably help to show the code that declares it.

Comment: It seems, that you're looking for `Console.KeyAvailable`

Comment: This question is too broad and opinion based. There are *many* ways of doing that

Comment: thanks everyone! all of the comments were very informative (except yours, Fabjan, see me after class) - I'll make sure to read up on all the options you guys listed and get my %*@$ together!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is create a property of type `string` called `Input`. In the setter of this property, if the value has changed, you call your method :

```
private string _input;
public string Input
{
    get { return _input; }
    set
    {
        if (_input != value)
        {
            _input = value;
            CallMethod();
        }
    }
}

private void CallMethod()
{
    Console.Write("Input has changed");
}

private void ReadFromConsole()
{
    Input = Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Another alternative, a bit similar but more flexible, would be to use events :

```
private event TextChangedHandler TextChanged;
public delegate void TextChangedHandler();

private string _input;
public string Input
{
    get { return _input; }
    set
    {
        if (_input != value)
        {
            _input = value;
            TextChanged?.Invoke();
        }
    }
}

private void CallMethod()
{
    Console.Write("Input has changed");
}

private void ReadFromConsole()
{
    TextChanged += CallMethod;

    Input = Console.ReadLine();
}
```